# Reusing Thread Object in a for loop

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, refactoring

I'm currently refactoring some code and I keep finding blocks like the one below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumSortThreads; i++) {
        logger.info("Starting sorting thread " + (i) + "/"
                + NumSortThreads + "... ");
        sorter = new FooSorter(batchQueue, fooQue, RsaveQueue,
                minSamples);
        Sorter = new Thread(sorter);
        Sorter.start();
    }
```

Can you reuse a thread object in this manner? It's important as later I go to terminate the thread (using one of the object's methods) and I'm not sure if it will actually kill all of the spawned threads.

I can't find any documentation on the matter but from what I know of Java I would assume that each time `new Thread(obj)` is called, it's killing the previous thread. This is partially based off the fact that I know java provides another object for Thread Groups (which is what the original author was probably going for).

Does this code produce `NumSortThreads` threads? Or does produce only one due to repeat instantiation?

Comment: You're not reusing it. You're spawning a new thread every iteration (which the `new` keyword indicates). Instantiating a new `Thread` does absolutely nothing to the `Thread` that you spawned.

Comment: So in other words, this code will spawn `NumSortThreads` threads.

Comment: So if I were to call sorter.terminate() (a method that gets the object to stop processing) would it successfully kill all Sorter threads?

Comment: Depends on how it's implemented, but I'm guessing that it'll kill a single thread at most. I'm going to expand on this in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is reusing a variable `Sorter`, not the thread objects referenced by it. Once you re-assign the variable

```
Sorter = new Thread(sorter);
```

it starts referencing a new thread object, and stops referencing the old thread.

> So if I were to call sorter.terminate() (a method that gets the object to stop processing) would it successfully kill all Sorter threads?

No, since each thread object has its individual `FooSorter` assigned to it in the constructor

```
sorter = new FooSorter(batchQueue, fooQue, RsaveQueue, minSamples);
Sorter = new Thread(sorter); // <<== each thread gets a new FooSorter
```

this would terminate only the last thread. If you would like to terminate all threads, you need to put them in a collection, and call `terminate` in the same way that you created them, i.e. in a loop.

Comment: Thank you! I feared as much; oh well, I guess I'm gonna be busy tonight.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you reuse a thread object in this manner? It's important as later I go to terminate the thread (using one of the object's methods) and I'm not sure if it will actually kill all of the spawned threads.

You are not reusing the thread object. You are simply reusing reference of type Thread. Note that since you are reusing the reference there will not be any references to previous thread object and is free to be GCed.

> Does this code produce NumSortThreads threads? Or does produce only one due to repeat instantiation?

This would create NumSortThreads thread. But at a given point of time do not expect that many to run because as I said with no live references they will be GCed.